# Which TTF file to use for properly showing Hindi fonts with conjuncts and which minsdk version should be targeted

Tags: android, sqlite, unicode

I am developing an application in Android. I want to show Hindi text for EditText, Buttons, textview, webview
 and also I need to get data from json parsing and store in Sqlite.

i have checked many sollutions but the following issues arise

Normal words in hindi can be rendered properly like सरल

the problem arises in words like नित्य

also words like प्र

My questions are

1) which ttf file should i use

2) which min sdk should i target

3) will the sqlite database support unicode

4) how to display data in webview it gets all messed up

is there a simple solution than using

```
TextView t = (TextView ) findViewById(R.id.hindi);
Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                                          "fonts/hindi.ttf");
        t.setTypeface(face);
        t.setText("Hindi font");
```

everywhere for textview like setting up a common file to call in res folder like we call strings.xml

Answer (score 0):

I found these ttf available on this link

[Android Fonts TTF](http://hindi-fonts.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Android-Fonts.zip)

try give it a go :)

For the second question the minSdk looks like to be API14 from what I read on this link

[Android 4.0 APIs](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.0.html)

Comment: have you tested this font

Answer (score 0):

I know, I am bit late here but this is a known bug for android. You may like to see this [thread](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4153)